# Making Alpine work all the way with Maildir

Tags: email, maildir

I'm converting a Linux machine over to using `~/Maildir/` instead of `~/mail/`.  One of the requirements is for Alpine to work with this new arrangement.  Using the maildir patch at http://www.alpine.x10host.com/alpine/info/maildir.html, I've been able to get Alpine to read incoming mail from `~/Maildir`, but it still won't read or save emails in that format.  The best I was able to come up with is this in `.pinerc`:

```
folder-collections=~/Maildir/ ~/Maildir/[]
```

But this only results in messages being saved in mbox format in `~/Maildir`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct setting:

```
folder-collections="Anything you want" #mc/INBOX.[]
```

This suggestion is found near the bottom of the patch.  Why it's not explained in the above webpage is a bit of a mystery.